# Find word in column and copy lines below on different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have source data which are not aligned to table.

[image: Example of source data]

I want to find text (e.g. Account), copy the two whole lines below the cell with the found text (Account) and paste them on a different Sheet. Then search down and do again until the data ends. Data should be pasted in the order it is reached.

The cell with word "Account" will be always in the column A. The search should be for the exact word "Account", because in the column can be cells which contain e.g. "Payer account".

This code shows me an error msg

> "Run-time error 438 - object doesnt support this property or method"

```
Private Sub Search_n_Copy()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, C As Range

With Worksheets("INPUT_2") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column A
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) ' set the dynamic range to be searched

    ' loop through all cells in column A and copy below's cell to sheet "Output_2"
    For Each C In rng
        If C.Value = "Account" Then
            C.Offset(-1, 0).Copy C.Offset.OUTPUT_2(-7, -1) ' use offset to put value in sheet "Output_2", column E
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Comment: What line returns the error? `C.Offset(-1, 0).Copy C.Offset.OUTPUT_2(-7, -1)` is wrong syntax.  Look at HELP for the `Offset` property.

Comment: What the value of cells do you want to get?  12 cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post doesn't point out what the error in your original code is.  Ron Rosenfeld has already covered that in the comment.

Here is another faster way (*as compared to looping*) which uses `.Find/.FindNext` to achieve what you want. It also doesn't copy the rows in a loop but copies in the end.

```
Private Sub Search_n_Copy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range, aCell As Range, bcell As Range
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = "Account"

    Set ws = Worksheets("INPUT_2")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bcell = aCell

            If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.Row + 2))
            Else
                Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.Row + 2)))
            End If

            Do
                Set aCell = .Columns(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bcell.Address Then Exit Do

                    If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngCopy = .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.Row + 2))
                    Else
                        Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.Row + 2)))
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        End If

        '~~> I am pasting to Output sheet. Change as applicable
        If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Rows(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir! You are the man, it works really nice!

Comment: I just wanted to edit the target array, where it should be pasted, but when I want to change Columns, it shows me '1004' runtime error, that the object has not been found, but have no idea why.

If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("OUTPUT_2").Columns(5).Rows(2)

Since I've searched it on the internet also and it was like that. Could you advise me, please?

Comment: You can't copy a complete row and  then paste it from a specific column. You will have to amend the code slightly for that. How many columns below the `Account` do you want to copy? 6 Columns?

Comment: Oh I see you have accepted another answer so I guess you do not need a solution anymore... :D

Comment: Nooo, I just wanted to accept it, that it is also solution, but Im using yours, mainly! :D

Oh yes, thats it. Exactly, just 6 columns.

Comment: Why are you jumping from one answer to the other. I have no issues in you accepting @Dy.lee 's answer but then stick with whatever you choose

Comment: Change `Set rngCopy = .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.Row + 2))` to `Set rngCopy = .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 1), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 6))` and change `Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.Row + 2)))` to `Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 1), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 6)))`. Finally change `If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Rows(1)` to `If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Cells(2,5)`

Comment: I have not noticed, that your answer has been unticked. I wanted to marked both answers as correct, since they are correct, but your fits much better, therefore I ticked your answer as correct and then wanted to ticked @Dy.lee 's as well, but base on your comment I've noticed, that your answer has been unticked, which I didnt want to. I am freshman here, so apologize for weird behaviour :)

Comment: no worries. see my last comment. Make those 3 changes and see if it works for you

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I have founded, that the rows below the header are variables - I mean, that sometime I need to copy 2 rows and othertime 4 rows. Would it be possible to set it, that the it will find the header (Account), then check how many rows are filled, until there is blank cell  - copy those data as previously and then search for other header. Could I ask you for your advice one more time, please? :)

Comment: I can but I want you to try it. After you find the cell `If rngCopy Is Nothing Then` loop down and check if the cell is empty or not

Answer (score 1):

The codle would be like this. This code  Use variant.

```
Private Sub Search_n_Copy()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, C As Range
    Dim vR(), n As Long, k As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("INPUT_2") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
        .Columns("e").ClearContents
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column A
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) ' set the dynamic range to be searched

        ' loop through all cells in column A and copy below's cell to sheet "Output_2"
        For Each C In rng
            If C.Value = "Account" Then
                For j = 1 To 2
                    n = n + 1
                    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 6, 1 To n)
                    For k = 1 To 6
                        vR(k, n) = C.Offset(j, k - 1) ' use offset to put value in sheet "Output_2", column E
                    Next k
            End If
        Next C
        If n > 0 Then
            Set Ws = Sheets.Add '<~~~  Sheets("your sheet name")
            With Ws
                .Range("a1").Resize(n, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Using arrays is also faster. I would have copied the entire excel range to array and then looped the array :D