# VBA - Type Mismatch Error for copying cells linked to a certain keyword in a column

Tags: excel, vba, search, keyword

I am trying to automate bank statement reconciliation. I need to find a certain word in column B, then copy the value 4 columns to right of that word, as well as the value found 3 rows down and one column to the left. My goal is to find these two values every times that keyword is found and copy them to a second sheet. I'm experiencing a type mismatch error that I can't seem to figure out.

First off, I'm as new as can be to macros.  I've adapted my code from this post: [VBA - find specific word in column and copy the below's cell on different sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779297/vba-find-specific-word-in-column-and-copy-the-belows-cell-on-different-sheet). The main adaption seems to be finding two separate values rather than two whole lines, which seem to require some extra lines of code incorporating a second range. The error occurs when I try and set the second range, on this line:

```
Set rngCopy2 = .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Row) + 3) & (.Cells(aCell.Column) - 1)
```

I tried changing .Rows to .Columns  where it's aCell.Column but that didn't seem to work. I'm positively stumped, and would appreciate any help someone could provide.

Note that I made some small edits to the syntax of the code and added .Cells before the aCell when setting ranges.

Also, as a separate and quick question, if I have a name in a cell that could be anywhere from 5 to 18 characters long but that is followed by a constant such as "ABC Staff", is there a way to take everything in that cell up until it says "ABC Staff"?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim rngCopy2 As Range
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = "Salary Transfer"

Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")

With ws
    Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopy = .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Column + 4))
            Set rngCopy2 = .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Row) + 3) & (.Cells(aCell.Column) - 1)
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Column + 4)))
            Set rngCopy2 = Union(rngCopy2, .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Row + 3) & .Cells(aCell.Column - 1)))
        End If

        Do
            Set aCell = .Columns(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngCopy = .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Column + 4))
                    Set rngCopy2 = .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Row) + 3) & (.Cells(aCell.Column) - 1)
                Else
                     Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Column + 4)))
                    Set rngCopy2 = Union(rngCopy2, .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Row + 3) & .Cells(aCell.Column - 1)))
                End If
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
    End If

    If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Rows(1)
    If Not rngCopy2 Is Nothing Then rngCopy2.Copy Sheets("Output").Rows(2)
End With
```

Comment: `Set rngCopy2 = .Rows(.Cells(aCell.Row) + 3) & (.Cells(aCell.Column) - 1)` is likely incorrect.  You have `.Rows(.Cells())&#`? If `aCell.row` is 1, and `aCell.Column` is also 1, that resolves to `.Rows(4)&0`? What exactly do you want that `.Rows()` to be?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Bruce. I've scrutinized it and am having a little trouble understanding it. I want that .Rows() to find the cell one column to the left and three rows down from aCell. This would be the range I'm setting for rngCopy2. I'm not sure what you mean in that sentence about having left both aCell.row and aCell.column both as 1. My apologies for the confusion!

Comment: Add `debug.print aCell.Row & ", " aCell.Column` right before that `Set` line. What does the [Immediate Window](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/) show?  I think what you want is `Set rngCopy2 = .Range(aCell.Offset(0,-1),aCell.Offset(3,0))`? or if it's a *single* cell, `Set rngCopy2 = .Cells(aCell.Column-1,aCell.Row+3)`?

Comment: It is a single cell that I'm looking for. I've incorporated Set rngCopy2 = .Cells(aCell.Column-1,aCell.Row+3) for the setting of both ranges, as well as the setting of both Unions - set rngCopy2 = Union(rngCopy2, .Cells(aCell.Column - 1, aCell.Row + 3)). Now that part of the code seems to be working. However, the copying of the range (at the bottom of the above code) doesn't seem to work, running crashes Excel. If I'm looking to copy rngCopy and rngCopy2 for every times the keyword is found (different output each time), is that rngCopy2.Copy in the right place? And is the Union line correct?