# VBA Copying cells linked to a certain keyword in a column

Tags: excel, vba, search, keyword

I am trying to automate bank statement reconciliation. I need to find a certain keyword in column B, then copy the value 4 columns to right of that word, and paste it into a separate sheet for each instance that that keyword is located. I'm 100% new to macros. I've adapted my code from this post: [VBA - find specific word in column and copy the below's cell on different sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779297/vba-find-specific-word-in-column-and-copy-the-belows-cell-on-different-sheet). When I run it, I only get the value from the cell on the first line that is four columns to the right of column B copy pasted into column A of the second worksheet all the way down to the last possible row. I think my issue is that the loop is not working (maybe I need to incorporate a count so that it find the corresponding value for each instance I find the keyword?), or maybe I'm setting ranges and/or unions wrong. Trying to use offset instead of cells makes excel not respond. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've added a picture example below of a bank transfer entry put into excel. I want the value 4 columns to the right of "Salary Transfer" copied into a second worksheet, "Output". I've put X's to block out sensitive information. Sorry for not being able to figure out how to get the image to show on here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvXCg.jpg

I did post a similar question about a type mismatch error a couple hours ago that was trying to look for two separate values that were offset from the keyword, I'm just trying to simplify it now by finding the one offset value and if I figure that out, then I can do it for the other value (one that is one column to the left and the rows down from the keyword) - mods, hopefully me posting this is all right, my apologies if it is not.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = "Salary Transfer"

Set Ws = Worksheets("Summary")

With Ws
Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell

    If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
        Set rngCopy = .Cells(aCell.Column + 4)
    Else
        Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Cells(aCell.Column + 4))
    End If

    Do
        Set aCell = .Columns(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

            If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = .Cells(aCell.Column + 4)
            Else
                Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Cells(aCell.Column + 4))
            End If
        Else
            Exit Do
    End If
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
End If

If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Columns(1)
End With
```

Comment: `.Cells(aCell.Column + 4)` is not right because Cells needs a row and column input. You can use `acell.Offset(,4)`. There might be other issues, but sort that out first.

Comment: I've now tried using Set rngCopy = .Cells(aCell.Offset(, 4)) with or without a 0 before the comma, and either way I'm getting an "invalid procedure call or argument" error. Should I be trying to do something like Set rngCopy = .Range(aCell.Offset(, 4)) ? That doesn't work, but maybe my syntax is wrong?

Comment: You just need `Set rngCopy = aCell.Offset(, 4)` as Offset is a relative reference to a range.

Comment: Oh man thank you so much I knew my issue was some nonsense, I've got it working! Now I just need to get it working for the other offset value, should only take a few minutes, will respond if I need any more help - thanks again!

Also, as a separate, quick question, if I have a name in a cell that could be anywhere from 5 to 18 characters long but that is followed by a constant such as "ABC Staff", is there a way to take everything in that cell up until it says "ABC Staff"?

Comment: Yes, but it's one question per question as it were. You can probably google a solution to that or check out Excel's text formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this will do what you're looking for:

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet, rCell As Range
Dim strSearch As String: strSearch = "Salary Transfer"

For Each rCell In Intersect(Ws.UsedRange, Ws.Range("B1").EntireColumn).Cells
    If UCase(rCell.Value2) = UCase(strSearch) Then
        Sheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Intersect(rCell.EntireRow, Ws.Columns(6)).Value
    End If
Next rCell
```

There's more efficient ways using the find and arrays, but this should just get you to the finish line.